# Allowing PHP $_POST with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, post, url-rewriting, http-post

I'm not so good on htaccess but was happy with what I had done so far until I noticed my $_post variables were not being processed because of the rewrite signiture within my htaccess file (SIGH)

My objective was to read the url and determine it's path and location from php and it's $_SERVER['request_uri'] method, which works fine. Everything after http://mydomain.com/ gets ripped apart and used as data hence the need for htaccess.

my htaccess:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc

Options +FollowSymlinks

<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

IndexIgnore *

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?/

<FilesMatch "(\.jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)$">
  ErrorDocument 404 "File Not Found"
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)\.htm $1.php [L,NC]
```

my php: (baring in mind everything gets parsed through index.php)

The php is irrelevant to the problem as I know it should work. I have been testing the post variables by using print_r($_POST) and they are empty when submitted from a form. The obvious problem is down to my lack of knowledge with htaccess.

Just for this thread. lets say my index.php looked like this:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

?>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="test">
  <input type="submit" value="Test!">
</form>
```

online example here:
www.blueaspect.com <-- The form works!

Then by adding foo/ to the end of the url you'll see the file loaded is still index.php. Which is what I want but now the form does not work.

Please if anyone could help that would be much appreciated

Comment: What is the `RewriteCond` intended for? Why would you want to rewrite only POST url's? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: removing it still leaves me with the same problem. I was just trying to allow post requests

Comment: This is odd:  The server will be doing an internal rewrite, not a header redirect. The POST variables should survive this unscathed. Are you 100% sure there is no other rule kicking in causing a header redirect?

Comment: I uploaded a test on an old domain of mine:

http://www.blueaspect.com/ <--- the form works
http://www.blueaspect.com/blah/blah <--- the form doesn't work

Comment: I'm guessing I need a rewrite condition if request_uri is set to send post data to a certain script? I'm aware of the problem but have no idea how to fix it :z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AddType text/x-component .htc

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)?\.(sb|html|htm|php|asp|aspx)$ index.php
```

fixed that problem